# How to check airflow dag is running or not in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

How to check the airflow dag is running or not in chef  status check

Comment: I don't know what any of that means, please be more specific.

Comment: Airflow  https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/      not getting how to check the dag is running.   My main moto is do deploy my application in Airflow master and worker when dag is not deploying

Comment: How is this related to Chef in any way?

Comment: I want to deploy  code in 2 nodes but when dag is not running on only one node. we can check with ps -ef  in only one node but other node also we have to deploy. But dag is running in one node i dont want to deploy in both nodes.   But how can we check when i am in first node where we could not able to check process in another node

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chef roles or node attributes to control what gets run. If you are unfamiliar with these please see our tutorials at https://learn.chef.io/

And in the future, please don't cross-post to Slack when you've been asked for information on here, it mostly gets seen by the same people and makes it seem like you think our time isn't valuable.

UPDATE:

Handled more directly on Slack, user was trying to use a non-existent feature in chef-provisioning.